# Schengen visa to Austria - start date on passport is a day after the arrival date

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, austria

I received a Schengen visa to Austria for me and wife from the Austrian Embassy in India. But, the Visa start date on her passport is a day after the arrival date, on my Visa it's accurate. VFS has asked me to apply for a correction. How long will it take? I haven't found anything online.

Instead of 22/03/19 she received 23/03/19. It is surely a mistake on their part as the details provided were accurate and I received a correct Visa. VFS has asked for a cover letter to state the correction.

Comment: How long did VFS say it would take?

Comment: You have plenty of time before the travel date, i think a correction within 1 month is easily going to be possible. If time was short i would have changed the flight but still kept the passports with me.

Comment: In the UK, corrections could take up to 6-7 weeks, it really depends on how busy they are at that time (and also on the country of course). You should ask the person who told you to apply for a correction, though if they are telling you to do that hopefully that means they know it will be done in time...

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Yes a bit of time on hand but remember February ends on 28th :(. Anyway, VFS said it could take even 2 days or may be 7 days. Mistake is on their part so I hope they pull up their socks and do it quickly. I will keep this thread posted as it will help lot of travellers.

Comment: I got the Visa corrected and it took roughly 7 days including a weekend. Always make sure you get Visa stamp checked before leaving VFS